Left side of LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar (actual: varbinary). What's an alternative to converting from varbinary to varchar?
I have the following query on dune.com:
SELECT
  th.value / 1e18 as amount,
  tr.success,
  th."from",
  th.to,
  tr.hash,
  tr.data,
FROM
  table1 tr
  table2 th ON tr.hash = th.evt_hash
WHERE
  th.to = sjhd21
  AND tr.success = true
  AND (
    th.value / 1e18 > 10
    OR th."from" = h123g
  ) 
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0xbc4b3365%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x447e346f%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x0100670b%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x2d1fb389%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0xb9181611%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x47e7ef24%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0xdb6b5246%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0xf80dec97%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x8129fc1c%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x8da5cb5b%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x7729d644%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0xd6c9b6a5%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x143531c0%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x715018a6%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x4fb2e45d%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0xf2fde38b%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x4f065632%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x7a78b9c7%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x535b355c%'
  AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0x9c66c25d%'

This query takes a long time to process. I assume this is because I'm converting the data column in the WHERE clause.
If I don't convert it I get this error:

Left side of LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar (actual: varbinary)

I have tried using a CTE to convert the data but it still takes just as long so I gave up on that.
What's an alternative to this? Is there an expression that will work with data as varbinary?

I don't use dune but looks like you are only looking at the first 4 bytes so should be able to use varbinary_substring and not in

The casting on the left hand argument of the (not) like is quite probably the cause of the slowness, especially if that column is indexed.
Looking at the conditions you have there, you aren't really using the full-blown power of the like operator, but only using it to check for a prefix. This can be done more efficiently with the varbinary_starts_with function:
AND NOT varbinary_starts_with(tr.data, 0xbc4b3365)
-- etc...


AND CAST(tr.data AS varchar) NOT LIKE '0xb9181611%'
If these are essentially numbers, can you do AND NOT (  tr.data > 3105363473 and tr.data < 3105363474 )
Treat them as numbers or store a number version so you can do a great than/less than.

@PaulManley this would only work if you know something about the length of the value. In the OP's query and in my solution, the condition will match values like 0xbc4b336511111111. With your solution, it won't.

@Mureinik Don't know about Dune, but many DBMSs allow you to do AND NOT (tr.data > 0xbc4b3365 AND tr.data < 0xbc4b3366)
